# Injecting/Inserting/Adding H.264 SEI

Tags: gstreamer, h.264

I would like to embed data into an H.264 stream using *User data unregistered SEI message*s.  What is the easiest or proper way to achieve this in GStreamer?

I found [this commit](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/commit/538aae24042b0f6b241911d4dc707a56b34b4d1f). It inserts SEI messages (of another kind) into the H.264 NAL stream by modifying a GstBuffer, employing a GstByteReader to find a NAL start code etc.  I find this quite low level and was hoping to find an easier solution, using [GstH264Parser](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-libs/html/gst-plugins-bad-libs-h264parser.html).

Ideally, my data would be added to the RAW video frames using [GstMeta](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/meta.html) before encoding.  I would then put another element after the encoder to take my GstMeta data and embed it as SEI messages.

Comment: I can't answer using gst, but SEI goes in as a separate NAL with nal_unit_type = 6. Start of NAL is always byte-alligned so that buffer can just be appended/inserted into the bitstream.

Answer (score 2):

Using appsrc and funnel element. Generating SEI and injecting it into appsrc. The whole pipeline is as below.

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 funnel name=f \
appsrc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=au ! queue ! f. \
videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=au, profile=baseline ! queue ! f. \
f. ! queue ! h264parse ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=nal ! filesink location=dump.h264
```

Refer: [【GStreamer】基于NTP+SEI的视频流传输时延测量](https://blog.csdn.net/Cheers724/article/details/99822937)